How to change Mathematica 14 preferences by modifying application file(s), rather than by using the graphical user interface (GUI)?
I'm running Mathematica 14 on Windows 11. Is there a way to modify Mathematica's preferences by modifying one or more application files, rather than using Mathematica's graphical user interface (GUI) to do so?
Specifically, I'm looking to change "Input Assistance Settings" by modifying application file(s), rather than using Mathematica's GUI?
In Windows, one can access "Input Assistance Settings" through the GUI by selecting Edit > Preferences on the menu bar. When the Preferences window appears, select Interface on the left-hand side of the window. The "Input Assistance Settings" subsection is about halfway down the page. It has four items with checkboxes:

Does anyone here know if there is a (human-readable) options file that one can use to set the state -- on ("checked") or off ("unchecked") -- of each setting (i.e., checkbox)?
(By the way, you may rightly wonder why I don't simply check/uncheck the boxes in the GUI under Preferences. The reason is that I'm running another installation of Mathematica in tandem with some proprietary software developed by another company working in collaboration with Wolfram. The proprietary software will not allow me to access Mathematica's preferences through the GUI in that installation of Mathematica.)

You ask to modify files on disk, but another option you might have is to change settings programmatically (instead of using the GUI). This is possible. You can use SetOptions on $FrontEnd. See also Options[$FrontEnd]. Anything you can change in Format -> Option Inspector is available this way. If you search the option inspector, you might find the settings corresponding to what you see in the Preferences window. Not a full answer, but I hope this is a good starting point for you to develop a solution.

Another comment is that any changes you make to settings (in the GUI or otherwise) are recorded as a literal SetOptions[$FrontEnd, ...] command in the file $UserBaseDirectory/FrontEnd/init.m. If you just see SetOptions[$FrontEnd, VersionedPreferences->True] in this file, then there are separate settings for each front end version, and which you'll find in files named as 14.0_init.m.

@Andrew Maybe you need way to the file C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\14.0\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\SystemResources\Preferences.nb ?
